# FFmpeg with libx264 skipped many frames during re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I found a strange problem with FFmpeg 4.1.3 when I re-encode this video file with libx264 and I use bitrate 8000k mode.

```
ffmpeg -y -i src.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -b:v 8000k dst.mp4
```

Source video (28 seconds) shows 3 images.

After re-encoding I see only 2 images and 3rd image is missing. I tested in latest VLC player 3.0.6, MPC-HC, Media player in Windows 10.

If I use crf video encoding instead of bitrate everything is fine.

Source video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gK06QtN8IqQNwAZeJdg7lbQgX0tkjaOn

Comment: Very interesting. 3rd image ist missing for me in VLC but corrupt with an old version of ffmpeg's s/w decoder. Plays fine with CUDA decoder, both directly and via FFmpeg. Also with current ffplay. Does it happen with x264 standalone?.

Comment: I didn't check yet. With NVENC it's OK for 8000k bitrate.The problem is only with libx264. I decided to submit a bug-report for authors of FFmpeg.

Comment: This appears to be a bitstream issue, so it should be submitted to x264 project.